# Bash shell scripting to update filenames in loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have to create a shell script to execute the following.

```
for file in /dir
do
    somecommand $file /newdir/outputname.txt
done
```

My problem is for each loop I have to give new name for "outputname.txt' , like 'output1.txt' in loop1 , 'output2.txt' in loop2 and so on. How to do that ?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: use a variable and increment it. Something like `let i=$i+1`

Answer (score 1):

I can do this such as following.

```
i=1
for file in /dir
do
    somecommand $file /newdir/output${i}.txt
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This would not overwrite files that already exists in /newdir.

```bash
i=0
for file in /dir/*; do
    until [[ ! -e /newdir/output$((++i)).txt ]]; do
        continue
    done
    somecommand "$file" "/newdir/output${i}.txt"
done
```

*****  Always place arguments with variables around double-quotes to prevent word splitting. (Specially not necessary in `[[ ]]`)

Comment: The code highlighting appears to catch wrong language(looks like `C` or something). I'd suggest adding `<pre><code class="bash> ... </code></pre>` to your answer, or only `<code class="bash"> ... </code>`.

Comment: @quapka Thanks the fix is good enough. (Update: I instead used `<!-- language: lang-bash -->`)

Answer (score 0):

To put @rpax suggestion into a full answer:

```
i=0
for file in /dir
do
    i=$(($i+1))
    mv $file "/${newdir}/output_${i}.txt"
done
```